# Crash when use SURFDetector in EmguCv

Tags: c#, crash, emgucv

I cannot use the `SURFDetector` object, because the program crashes.

I'm using the version 2.4.9 of Emgu (downloaded form [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.9-alpha/)), and I've followed the instructions about adding the OpenCV dependencies ([link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Have_you_copied_the_OpenCV_dlls_to_the_execution_directory.3F)):

> For EMGU CV version >=2.4 cudart64_42_9.dll, cvextern.dll, npp64_42_9.dll, opencv_calib3dXXX.dll, opencv_contribXXX.dll, opencv_coreXXX.dll, opencv_features2dXXX.dll, opencv_flannXXX.dll, opencv_highguiXXX.dll, opencv_imgprocXXX.dll, opencv_legacyXXX.dll, opencv_mlXXX.dll, opencv_nonfreXXX.dll, opencv_objectdetectXXX.dll, opencv_videoXXX.dll, where XXX is the OpenCV version number.

I also added referencies to `Emgu.CV.dll`, `Emgu.Util.dll` and `Emgu.CV.UI`. In order to try to resolve the problem, I tried to add also `Emgu.CV.GPU.dll` and `opencv_gpuXXX.dll`, wit no success.

I'm working on a 64-bit PC, with Windows 7 installed, but my project is built for x86, and I'm using the dependencies for x86 architectures. Before using the `SURFDetector` object, everything worked fine.

The crash happens when the program reaches the following line:

```
SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);
```

The program throws two kind of exceptions (yes, two), and I cannot realize why it throws one rather than the other:

1. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in mscorlib.dll
2. System.DllNotFoundException in Emgu.CV.dll (impossible to load
   the 'cvextern' DLL), with a strange error code (HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

In both cases, VisualStudio 2012 opens a new tab, called "Source not available" or something like that (I'm not sure about the exactly words used by the english version of VisualStudio, because I'm using the italian one).

EDIT: I want to add to the foregoing, that the executable file of the example provided with the library, called SURFFeature, works perfectly...

Comment: I solved using the [version 2.4.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.0/).

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: You can refer to the sample code included in the version 2.4.0 of EmguCV